# Multiple word search in field

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I recently started playing around with lucene.net for an internal project at work. I am looking to create a type of autocomplete using lucene.net. My index stores the display name and when i do a wildcard search i.e James* it works fine.

The problem seems to be when the space comes between the word i.e. James Bon* It seems to forget the first word and start to try and match on the Bon.

Not sure if I am doing anything wrong but tried using a few of the different analyzers but no luck.

Anyone got any ideas that could set me on the right track?

**28/11/2012**

After looking again at my project, I realised that I was using a MultiFieldQueryParser to try and search multiple fields. Tried the suggestion of changing the DefaultOperator but had no luck.

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
var mparser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new string[] { "displayname", "company", "email" }, analyzer);
```

Comment: Have you tried `queryParser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);` ?

Comment: "Lucene supports single and multiple character wildcard searches within single terms (not within phrase queries)." [Source](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

By default Lucene.net performs an `OR` search on the provided terms, not an `AND` search. Use this code to change it:

```
parser.SetOperator(QueryParser.DEFAULT_OPERATOR_AND);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just performing multi word query on a single field then you want multi word to behave like 'like' operator then use below line.

```
parser.DefaultOperator = QueryParser.Operator.AND;
```